# Java API to encode special XML characters?

Tags: java, xml, encode

Is there a Java API which encodes XML special characters: <, >, &, ", '

My code reads a file and creates an XML out of it. As we are reading the file, is there way to escape these characters without hard-coding String.replace on them?

URLEncode encodes everything, including spaces, so I can't use that.

Thanks

Comment: your code is writing XML from a DOM?

Comment: [XMLStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html): *However the writeCharacters method is required to escape & , < and > For attribute values the writeAttribute method will escape the above characters plus " to ensure that all character content and attribute values are well formed.*

Answer (score 0):

If you create your XML from a DOM, then the special chars will be escaped.

For example

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Comment;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class NewXML {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();

        // create the root element node
        Element element = doc.createElement("root");
        doc.appendChild(element);

        // create a comment node given the specified string
        Comment comment = doc.createComment("This is a comment");
        doc.insertBefore(comment, element);

        // add element after the first child of the root element
        Element itemElement = doc.createElement("item");
        element.appendChild(itemElement);

        // add an attribute to the node
        itemElement.setAttribute("myattr", "attr>value");

        // create text for the node
        itemElement.insertBefore(doc.createTextNode("te<xt"), itemElement.getLastChild());

        prettyPrint(doc);

    }

    public static final void prettyPrint(Document xml) throws Exception {
        Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        tf.transform(new DOMSource(xml), new StreamResult(out));
        System.out.println(out.toString());
    }
}
```

generates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--This is a comment--><root>
<item myattr="attr&gt;value">te&lt;xt</item>
</root>
```

ps. example extracted from this site - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/dom/create-dom-document-from-scratch/